# Heat pump always turns on with fan!

Tags: hvac

[image: unit control panel]

If I turn my fan on on my thermostats the heat pump turns on with heat or cool setting

There is a jumper wired from green to w1(the heat pump)

If I move the jumper to r (24v) and g and turn on the dip swith 8 (on - fan comes on with call for heat off - fan comes on with cool call) will it fix my problem?

I’m assuming I would have to adjust the dip switch for summer or winter?

We recently got a wood stove in step down den and it has a blower so we want to run the fan to circulate the heat from it

Comment: What make and model is your air-handler/indoor-unit/furnace?

Comment: TZ-3 totalzone trolatemp I have a heat pump and a thermostat on my 1st and second floors all electric units air conditioning and heating back up is comfort

Comment: No, that's your *zone board* -- I'm asking about the actual *air handler* that has the indoor coils for the heat pump in it.

Comment: Comfortmaker model fxm4x3600A

Answer (score 1):

### Remove the jumper to G, turn dip switch 8 on, and enjoy.

The jumper between W1/Y1 and G on your board is what is causing the fan problem here.  So, I would remove the jumper to the G wire (from W1/Y1) from the zone board with the indoor unit OFF at the service switch, flip dip switch 8 on the zone board to ON to make it so that the zone board calls for fan when a heat call comes in, turn the service switch on the indoor unit back ON, and enjoy your newfound comfort!

Comment: Should I switch dip switch to off during cooling season? If so do I need to turn the main off to slip a dip switch

Comment: @AndreaJialanella -- you do not need to change the DIP switch between heating and cooling seasons.

Comment: Y1 is jumpered from w1 and w1 is jumpered to g(remover and fan works) should I also remove the y1 to w1 jumper ? If so nothing will be running to w1.      Should a jumper run from w1 to w2?

Comment: @AndreaJialanella -- the Y1/W1 jumper needs to stay in your setup btw (sorry for the extremely delayed reply!)